# How do i get multiple scattered line charts on top of each other in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, charts, chart.js

I am using chartjs to make charts in my application.

The data is given as a scatter line chart:

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
        data: [{
            x: -10,
            y: 0
        }, {
            x: 0,
            y: 10
        }, {
            x: 10,
            y: 5
        }]
    }]
} });
```

I am trying to get two line charts on top of each other but i am not able to do so. I want it like the image below -

[image]

How do i do this?

PS: In my scattered chart the y axis is time.